Не работает обработка платежа aiogram 3
Есть следующий код для покупки промокода
PRICE = LabeledPrice(label='Vip', amount=1000 * 100)


@router.message(Command('buy'))
async def buy_vip(message: Message, bot: Bot):
    await bot.send_invoice(chat_id=message.chat.id,
                           title='Тестовый платеж',
                           description='test test test',
                           payload='test-payload',
                           provider_token=TOKEN_PAY,
                           currency='rub',
                           prices=[PRICE],
                           start_parameter='vip-access',
                           max_tip_amount=5000,
                           suggested_tip_amounts=[1000, 2000, 4000, 5000],
                           request_timeout=10
                           )


@router.pre_checkout_query()
async def pre_checkout(query: PreCheckoutQuery, bot: Bot):
    await bot.answer_pre_checkout_query(query.id, ok=True)

''' Эта функция должна срабатывать при успешном платеже '''
@router.message(???)
async def success_buy(message: Message):
    promocode = create_promocode()

    text = f'Оплата успешно прошла!\nВаш промокод: <code>{promocode}</code>'

    await message.answer(text=text)

Необходимо, чтобы после оплаты, срабатывала функция success_buy
Как правильно написать этот обработчик?
